# Trie mechanism in C

Tags: c, data-structures, trie

I'm totally beginner and trying to create a trie structure for spellcheck. I've already read lots of documentation but still have gaps in my understanding and if somebody explains I would be grateful. Sorry of my questions looks noob, but I'm basicly a noob.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LENGTH 45
#define N 27


char word[LENGTH + 1];

typedef struct trie
{
    char data; //letter(character)
    struct trie* child[N]; //array of pointers to the next trie
    int leaf; //is word ending here
}trie;
```

I'm setting `int leaf` as `0` for all new tries. When I completed inserting the word I'm changing the `int leaf` to `1` so I'll know if the word I'm checking is there.

What if I left that `leaf = 1` for another word? How program will know if the leaf is true for some other word or not? Should I make an array of pointer or should I start over with a different approach? TIA

[my trie node sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRjUo.jpg)

Comment: "What if I left that leaf = 1 for another word? How program will know if the leaf is true for some other word or not?" Can you elaborate with an example of what you're thinking might go wrong here?

Comment: I’m not entirely sure I understand the question, but another word should never find its way to that node. The paths are unique. If you have one word that is a suffix of another, sure it happens, but then just don’t change existing nodes, except perhaps for adding out edges. If you want words to sit in leaves, you need a sentinel character to prevent one word being a prefix of another, and then two words never end in the same leaf, by construction.

Comment: "Leave `leaf=1` for *another word"?* That makes no sense. Exactly one string leads to that node and ends there, and `leaf=1` means that the string that ends there is a word. It cannot correspond to a word that ends somewhere else.

Comment: @Welbog let assume I'll add to words "get" and "put" in the third layer they will both end with "t". Will they share the same "t" node or there will be separate nodes for each "t" ? Because this is how I imagine a trie structure after seeing the word search diagrams. My concern is what if I'll search for "aet" and obviously it's not a word but program will find a path because "aetna" has been implemented and will find a leaf because of "get" etc. Sorry but I'm fairly new so I can't understand the mechanism so well.

Comment: A trie is very memory hungry, an alternative is a [ternary search tree](https://github.com/drankinatty/ternary_st) which has a fraction of the memory storage requirement and as good or better performance.

Comment: @cetin nodes along paths are unique. The t in get and put are different nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quick look at your structure and tried to implement a quick and dirty insertion and lookup. I changed the name 'leaf' to 'flag', since it isn't a leaf but a flag that indicates that we have a word, rather than some prefix.

```c
#define N 26
typedef struct trie {
  char data;
  struct trie* children[N];
  int flag;
} trie;

// all zero data...
trie TRIE_TEMPLATE;

#define edge_idx(c) (c - 'a')
trie *next(trie *node, char c)
{
  trie *n = node->children[edge_idx(c)];
  if (!n) {
    // no such edge yet...
    n = malloc(sizeof *n);
    if (!n) abort(); // error handling
    *n = TRIE_TEMPLATE;
    n->data = c;
    node->children[edge_idx(c)] = n;
  }
  return n;
}

void insert(trie *root, char const *word)
{
  trie *n = root;
  for (char const *c = word; *c; c++) {
    n = next(n, *c);
  }
  n->flag = 1; // tag final node as a word
}

int contains(trie *root, char const *word)
{
  trie *n = root;
  for (char const *c = word; *c; c++) {
    n = n->children[edge_idx(*c)];
    if (!n) return 0;
  }
  return n->flag;
}
```

I haven't tested it that well, so don't trust it, but as you can see I use a template node that is all zeros (a global variable) to initialise new nodes. That sets the data, children and flag to zero. (It is not standard compliant, because NULL and zero are not necessarily the same thing, but it probably is, and for a quick prototype it is fine).

So nodes have the flag set to zero initially. In the insertion, I set the flag to 1 at the end of the string, so only the final node gets the flag. Not any of the nodes leading up to there. If we insert a prefix of an existing node, we will not make new nodes, but set the flag in the appropriate node. If we add a word, where the trie already has a prefix, it will not modify the existing node.

At least, that is how it is supposed to work, and with this quick test, it is what I see:

```c
int main(void)
{
  trie root = TRIE_TEMPLATE;
  insert(&root, "foo");
  insert(&root, "bar");

  printf("fo %s in trie\n",
         contains(&root, "fo") ? "is" : "is not");
  printf("foo %s in trie\n",
         contains(&root, "foo") ? "is" : "is not");

  printf("ba %s in trie\n",
         contains(&root, "ba") ? "is" : "is not");
  printf("bar %s in trie\n",
         contains(&root, "bar") ? "is" : "is not");

  // bar and baz share a prefix, but that is fine...
  printf("baz %s in trie\n",
         contains(&root, "baz") ? "is" : "is not");
  insert(&root, "baz");
  printf("baz %s in trie\n",
         contains(&root, "baz") ? "is" : "is not");


  // after inserting ba, it is there, and bar and baz are
  // also there. It doesn't matter that ba is a prefix
  insert(&root, "ba");
  printf("ba %s in trie\n",
         contains(&root, "ba") ? "is" : "is not");
  printf("bar %s in trie\n",
         contains(&root, "bar") ? "is" : "is not");
  printf("baz %s in trie\n",
         contains(&root, "baz") ? "is" : "is not");

  // foobar already has a prefix in the trie, foo,
  // but when we insert it, that is not a problem.
  printf("foobar %s in trie\n",
         contains(&root, "foobar") ? "is" : "is not");
  insert(&root, "foobar");
  printf("foobar %s in trie\n",
         contains(&root, "foobar") ? "is" : "is not");

  return 0;
}
```